# How does routing work with Node.js modules?

Tags: node.js, routes, socket.io, npm

I would like to see which routes are added by a module using node.js.
For instance using Socket.io, I require /socket.io/socket.io.js, yet I do not see this in my public directory or the directory of socket.io:

[image]

```
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
      socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
      });
    </script>
```

The resource loads a file when I inspect the url:

[image]

```
http://localhost:3111/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

How can I use the rails equivalent of "rake routes"?

Answer (score 2):

The URL your browser requests does not have to map to a physical file on your filesystem. Socket.IO, for instance, adds scripts to your server's routes via [the `lib/static.js` file](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/static.js); check out the code and you'll see routes for JavaScripts, SWF resources, and more.

Comment: Socket.IO [loads it](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.io.js#L104) when you `require` SocketIO in your server-side code.